# Is alcohol forbidden in Islam and written clearly in the Quran?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, alcohol

Is alcohol halal/haram in Islam and written clearly in the Quran

Comment: shouldn't there be a rule that says you have to at least do some research before coming to ask a question on this forum? because I hear this being recited from the Qur'aan almost every year during Ramadaan.
such a silly question.
I would rather have preferred "Why was Alcohol made forbidden"

Answer (score 1):

> Is alcohol forbidden in Islam and written clearly in the Quran

Yes. It is directly haram in Quran.

Its in [Surat Al-Mā'idah](http://quran.com/5).

> 5:90
>
> **O you who have believed, indeed, intoxicants, gambling, [sacrificing on] stone alters [to other than Allah ], and divining arrows are but
>   defilement from the work of Satan, so avoid it that you may be
>   successful.**
>
> 5:91
>
> **Satan only wants to cause between you animosity and hatred through intoxicants and gambling and to avert you from the remembrance of
>   Allah and from prayer. So will you not desist?**

Answer (score 0):

The Arabic word used in al-Māʼidah 90-91 is khamr خمر which literally means “wine, fermented grape juice”. There has been a lively debate amongst the mufassirūn and the fuqahāʼ as to whether the prohibition of wine encompasses other alcoholic drinks. The classic position of the Hanafi school was that only wine is specifically forbidden.